# iOS Tab Replacement in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

What is complete replacement of iOS Tabs Replacement in Android.

I Know that Android is Android and we don't Imitate other platforms on Android. I have Studied [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

But All I want to have the replacment of iOS tabs in Android with following features.

1.) Stores Navigation flow for each tab, As in iOS there is navigation controller for each tab and we can have the previous state for each tab while switching from tab to tab.

2.) Desirable but not necessary- Double click on tab button will refresh the view with the root view as per in iOS.

3.) The animation while switching from tab to tab or with in Tab does not swipe the complete Tabs(including the TAB Bar). It means only the content of each Tab should be replaceable with separate Activity or something like this.

4.) In short User Experience must be similar to iOS Tab Bar.

What I have Tried so far.
1.) Added Tabs with TabHost on bottom of screen.But I Haven't got the stack navigation for each Tab separately.
(Something like: https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

2.) Also I have an idea of Using Stack (Java Collection Framework.) But that will be a headache to maintain all the stack by my self.

So, Guys In short:

Do you have any ideas of any **Third Party Library**, that I can use in my project without much problem to achieve all the features mentioned above?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [native tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and style it to seem like iOS ones.

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), and store/reload the "Natigation flow" at the onPause/onRestore methods in each Fragment or in the FragmentActivity when you change form one fragment to an other.

BTW, please don't do that. If you studied Pure Android, what's the point do you want to achieve? Android is Android and iOS is iOS, do not mix them please.

**UPDATE: 3 September 2017**

An other, and imho better, approach to do so is make use of the `Bottom Navigation`. Take a look to [materialdocs](http://www.materialdoc.com/bottom-navigation/) to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

[This one is best to implement iOS like tabs in Android](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

Like this: 
 
[image]